# Xcode conditionals list, where do I find them?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to learn about all possible conditionals that can be used on Xcode regarding the iPhone and iPad.

I have found the file "TargetConditionals.h" on 
Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/include/

but this file do not shows all possible conditionals, just a small set.

I don't see, for example, __IPHONE_3_1
and others.

As Apple docs as vague as hell, I as you guys where can I find a complete list with ALL conditionals?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Availability.h. I don't know if there's a list that compiles everything across all files, but this one has the iPhone/Mac OS X version conditionals.